# Dark mode not working for neumorphism in android ko

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface

I m adding code here:

The library Im using is :
https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism

In dark mode , its awful

```
  <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphImageView
                android:id="@+id/template_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

What should I do to solve this?
Im using kotlin for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a library, I would like to suggest a different library as a solution.

[link](https://github.com/CRED-CLUB/synth-android)

The problem you are experiencing may be a problem with the library.

Comment: thx ofr library suggestions, but cred library doesnt have all views support for now thast why im using above library while above library claims they have dark mode suport